# Kendo LinearGauge pointer.track element not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have made multiple searches across the web and little is said about this element. The documentation can only be found at

```
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/lineargauge#configuration-pointer.track
```

(Sorry, had to put the link in code block as I do not have enough reputation to post 2 links)

I wish to accomplish something similar to the following: [LinearGauge Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4InVp.png)

Without much documentation, I believe this is what the pointer.track element does. However, I could not get pointer.track to cause any visual change in the LinearGauge. Here's a test case I tried http://dojo.telerik.com/OkUwOs. Contrary to the documentation, no element was found behind the pointer upon inspection.

Comment: Can you describe what it is you want to accomplish? The example you posted is just an image that doesn't really explain much...

Comment: The orange part of the image is the indicator while the grey part would be the background, which i suppose is the pointer.track element. So the image would correspond to a value of around 60%.